# Query Gstreamer rtsp methods, like PLAY, DESCRIBE etc

Tags: c++, qt, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I can't figure out how to call rtsp methods with headers, for understanding:

I have an rtsp player on qt, I want to add the rtsp playback speed functionality, many vendors do this by sending a PLAY request with a Speed header,

[image]

but I don't understand how I can send this request from gstreamer.

Answer (score 0):

You set playback rate for the pipeline via a GstSegemnt. E.g. when issueing a seek command. See https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstsegment.html#GstSegment.
`rtspsrc` should then take care of sending the required header info to the RTSP server when initiating the session.

Comment: I have already realized that under the hood gstreamer calls these methods itself, I have already tried: 
` gdouble rate = 0.25; `
    `gint64 position;`
    `if (!gst_element_query_position (data->pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, &position)) { `
     `g_printerr ("Unable to retrieve current position.\n");`
   ` }`
   `gboolean re=gst_element_seek(_data->pipeline, rate, GST_FORMAT_TIME,`
                                   `GstSeekFlags(GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_SKIP),`
                                 ` GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, position, GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET,` `GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE); `

Comment: And I noticed that with `GST_SEEK_FLAG_SKIP` and `TRICKMODE`, when speed is more than 1 frames are dropped, and the `GST_SEEK_FLAG_INSTANT_RATE_CHANGE` flag does not work, gives an assertion failed error